# marker.setposition with label

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the program below that reads aircraft coordinates from a txt file and places a number of markers on Google Maps. Every 2 sec it reads the txt file again and pushes the markers to the new aircraft locations. This works fine with the original markers "moving" to the new positions. What I would like to do is add a label to the marker to show the height of each aircraft. To do this I need to generate the label after the txt file has been read but when I do it doesn't delete the old markers but adds new markers.

The portion of code below is working fine but without a variable labels. The relevant code is where var eplanezero is created. If I move this line of code anywhere within the setInterval(function (){ the eplanezero.setPosition will not function properly. I have tried dozens of various but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts appreciated. Note that this is only a portion of the code.

```
    moveMarker(map, playerIcon, enemyIcon);
}

function moveMarker(map, playerIcon, enemyIcon)
{
var eplanezero = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, icon: enemyIcon, label: "1"});

setInterval(function ()
{
    $.post("MISSION_ADMIN_radar.txt", function(dataenemy, status)
    {
    var latlnge = JSON.stringify(dataenemy);
    latlnge = latlnge.replace(/"/g,"");
    latlnge = latlnge.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g,"");

    CoordsEnemy = latlnge.split(";");

    var army = parseFloat(CoordsEnemy[0].substring(0));
    if (army == 2)//Own army = 1, Enemy = 2
        {
        var commaPos = CoordsEnemy[0].indexOf(',');
        var hyphenPos = CoordsEnemy[0].indexOf('+');
        var lat0 = parseFloat(CoordsEnemy[0].substring(4, commaPos));
        var long0 = parseFloat(CoordsEnemy[0].substring(commaPos + 1, CoordsEnemy[0].length));
        }
        eplanezero.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat0, long0));

        });
}, 2000);
```

The altitude is obtained from the same array that holds the lat and long. However, to place the variable Alt into the marker, I have to create variable eplanezero in the setInterval function so that it updates it every 2 secs. When I do this, it will not **move** the marker but **adds** a new marker, leaving the original marker in the old position.

The revised code is as follows:

```
    function moveMarker(map, playerIcon, enemyIcon)
{
//var eplanezero = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, icon: enemyIcon, label: "1"});

var eplanezero = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, icon: enemyIcon, label: Alt});

setInterval(function ()
{
    $.post("MISSION_ADMIN_radar.txt", function(dataenemy, status)
    {
    var latlnge = JSON.stringify(dataenemy);
    latlnge = latlnge.replace(/"/g,"");
    latlnge = latlnge.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g,"");

    CoordsEnemy = latlnge.split(";");

    var army = parseFloat(CoordsEnemy[0].substring(0));
    if (army == 2)//Own army = 1, Enemy = 2
        {
        var commaPos = CoordsEnemy[0].indexOf(',');
        var hyphenPos = CoordsEnemy[0].indexOf('+');
        var Alt0 = parseFloat(CoordsEnemy[0].substring(hyphenPos + 1 , CoordsEnemy[0].length));

        var lat0 = parseFloat(CoordsEnemy[0].substring(4, commaPos));
        var long0 = parseFloat(CoordsEnemy[0].substring(commaPos + 1, CoordsEnemy[0].length));
    var eplanezero = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, icon: enemyIcon, label: Alt});
        }    
        eplanezero.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat0, long0));    
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Where is the code to change the label from the updated data? Where does the altitude come from? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Where are you "attempting to redefine eplanezero with the updated label"?  Why don't you just set the new value (as you do with the position)?

Answer (score 0):

.setPosition must be a method that looks in the array and checks for previous coordinates. if the array doesn't contain any coordinates it places a new marker at the new coordinates, If the array does contain coordinates it "moves"the marker to the new location. Establishing the array within the loop deletes any previous array and the coordinates and therefore Google Map correctly places a new marker. Only by creating the array outside the loop will the method work correctly. Unfortunately this means that the label or the icon cannot be changed once the array is created.